# elasticsearch jackson error -- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory not seen although defined

Tags: java, json, maven, elasticsearch, jackson

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory` isn't seen in my project-- I am getting the following Exception as root cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory` is in [Jackson core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core), and this dependency is in thru elasticsearch:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

as a resolved dependency:

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j6aK.png)

i tried putting jackson-core directly as a dependency in `pom.xml` and it didn't help.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manually removed `fasterxml` from maven repository .m2 on disk and had Maven download again-- `Update Maven`. worked.

there was a funny looking file in that folder.